# Incorrect sql syntax in EpiServer DynamicDataStore LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq, episerver

I'm writing a query to retrieve some data from a `DynamicDataStore` in Episerver. When I run the code I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Here's the relevant query:

```
BlogContentStore store = new BlogContentStore();
IQueryable<UwlBlogPost> posts = store.Posts.Where(p => Blog == p.BlogId && p.ReadyToPost && p.PostOn <= DateTime.Now);
if (taggedPeople.Count() > 0 || taggedDepartments.Count() > 0 || taggedDepartments.Count() > 0)
{
    posts = posts.Where(p => p.PeopleTags.Intersect(taggedPeople).Count() > 0
        || p.DepartmentTags.Intersect(taggedDepartments).Count() > 0
        || p.KeywordTags.Intersect(taggedKeywords).Count() > 0);
}
posts = posts.OrderByDescending(p => p.PostOn).Take(DisplayCount);
```

The syntax for everything looks alright to me, and it compiles okay.

Comment: Sorry about the answer related to Find (deleted it now). Somehow I thought the question was about Find instead of DDS. *smh*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. Looking at the SQL server log I was able to see that the `Intersect` statements were not getting turned into SQL, so I decided to dynamicly create the query expression to get around it:

```
if (taggedPeople.Count > 0 || taggedDepartments.Count > 0 || taggedKeywords.Count > 0)
{
    ParameterExpression paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(UwlBlogPost), "p");
    Expression peopleTagsExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, "PeopleTags");
    Expression deptTagsExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, "DepartmentTags");
    Expression keywordTagsExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, "KeywordTags");

    Expression filterExpr = null;
    if(taggedPeople.Count > 0)
    {
        filterExpr = FilterLambda<string>(taggedPeople, peopleTagsExpr, paramExpr);
    }
    if(taggedDepartments.Count > 0)
    {
        Expression filter = FilterLambda<int>(taggedDepartments, deptTagsExpr, paramExpr);
        filterExpr = (filterExpr == null) ? filter : MatchAll ? Expression.And(filterExpr, filter) : Expression.Or(filterExpr, filter);
    }
    if(taggedKeywords.Count > 0)
    {
        Expression filter = FilterLambda<int>(taggedKeywords, keywordTagsExpr, paramExpr);
        filterExpr = (filterExpr == null) ? filter : MatchAll ? Expression.And(filterExpr, filter) : Expression.Or(filterExpr, filter);
    }

    posts = posts.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<UwlBlogPost, bool>>(filterExpr, new[] { paramExpr }));
}


private Expression FilterLambda<T>(List<T> tags, Expression field, ParameterExpression paramExpr)
{
    Expression firstTag = Expression.Constant(tags.First());
    Expression root = Expression.Call(field, tags.GetType().GetMethod("Contains"), firstTag);
    if (tags.Count > 1)
    {
        foreach (T tag in tags.Skip(1))
        {
            Expression singleTag = Expression.Constant(tag);
            Expression cond = Expression.Call(field, tags.GetType().GetMethod("Contains"), singleTag);
            root = MatchAll ?  Expression.And(root, cond) : Expression.Or(root, cond);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```